Scipy sparse solve prints: dgstrf info
The following code
from scipy.linalg.sparse import solve as spsolve
foo = spsolve(AMatrixT, dist)

prints into stdout
dgstrf info 10200

And if I inspect foo, it's all NaN. The shape of dist happens to be (10200, 1). I have uploaded the sparse AMatrixT matrix and the dense dist array as .npz files here. What does the output mean, and how can I stop it?
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
python                    3.11.4               h955ad1f_0 
scipy                     1.12.0          py311h08b1b3b_0  


I reported this to SciPy, and a fix is being made. https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/20993 However, it will take time, because 1) a release of SuperLU must be made 2) someone in SciPy must import the SuperLU release, and 3) a new release of SciPy must be made.

According to the source code, an info greater than zero and less than or equal to the number of columns in your matrix means that some factor is zero, and the matrix is singular.
You can also see this in the warning which is emitted:
/tmp/ipykernel_2415/2956153609.py:2: MatrixRankWarning: Matrix is exactly singular
  foo = spsolve(AMatrixT, dist)

Since your matrix has 10200 columns, this means the last matrix column is causing the singular warning.
Here is the source code which documents this:
 * info     (output) int*
 *          = 0: successful exit
 *          < 0: if info = -i, the i-th argument had an illegal value
 *          > 0: if info = i, and i is
 *             <= A->ncol: U(i,i) is exactly zero. The factorization has
 *                been completed, but the factor U is exactly singular,
 *                and division by zero will occur if it is used to solve a
 *                system of equations.
 *             > A->ncol: number of bytes allocated when memory allocation
 *                failure occurred, plus A->ncol. If lwork = -1, it is
 *                the estimated amount of space needed, plus A->ncol.

Source.

how can I stop it?

I am unsure how to do this. The context manager contextlib.redirect_stdout() does not work - the print statement is inside a compiled C extension. It does not have any kind of verbose or debug argument to control it.
You could avoid passing singular matrices to this function, but I don't know of a better way.
